# Mysql multiple tables left join last table

Tags: mysql

I have checked several threads on here and cannot find the answer to my question....
I am trying to do a mysql query with multiple tables and left join the last table. It does not like the left join and gives me no results when I include it. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

(I am using Joomla)

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT u.id as uid, CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as name1,
 u.grad as   grad, u.opt_out as opt_out
FROM #__bl_teams as t, #__bl_regions as r, #__users as u 
LEFT JOIN #__bl_paid as pd ON pd.u_id = u.id

WHERE u.team_id = t.id AND u.team_id != '' AND u.s_id = $sid 
AND ((t.id = $tid)OR($tid=0)) AND (t.id IN ($teamsfull)) 
AND ( (t.id IN(".$tc_teams."))OR(".$tc_id." = 0)) 
AND ((r.id = ".$mid.")OR(".$mid." = 0)) 
AND ((r.s_id = ".$sid.")OR(".$mid." = 0)) 
AND ( (FIND_IN_SET(t.id,r.teams) )OR(".$mid." = 0) ) 
AND u.id NOT IN($paidrows) AND u.id NOT IN ($rsrows) GROUP BY u.id";
    $db->setQuery($query, $pageNav->limitstart, $pageNav->limit);
    $rows50 = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Why are you mixing old style joins and 'new' (1992) style? Wouldn't it be more readable if you use `inner join` for the other joins? As for your issue, I don't see any immediate syntax errors, but maybe there's an error (incorrect table name?) that makes the query fail. If that failure isn't checked for properly, it may seem like the query returns no rows.

Comment: I checked the table names and they are correct

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing old-style joins and new style joins.  That is your problem.  The table aliases aren't recognized throughout the `from` statement, the way you expect them to be.  Buried in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) is this warning:

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

So, rewrite your query using explicit joins and that will fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the ctual tables, but this query is too long and will have unexpected results results. Anyways, Left join the other tables too.

```
query = "SELECT DISTINCT u.id as uid, CONCAT(u.first_name,' ',u.last_name) as name1, 
u.grad as   grad, u.opt_out as opt_out

FROM #__users as u 

LEFT JOIN #__bl_paid as pd ON pd.u_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN #__bl_teams as t ON t.u_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN #__bl_regions as r ON r.u_id = u.id

WHERE u.team_id != '' 
AND u.s_id = $sid 
AND ((t.id = $tid)
OR($tid=0)) 
AND (t.id IN ($teamsfull)) 
AND ( (t.id IN(".$tc_teams."))
OR(".$tc_id." = 0)) 
AND ((r.id = ".$mid.")
OR(".$mid." = 0)) 
AND ((r.s_id = ".$sid.")
OR(".$mid." = 0)) 
AND ( (FIND_IN_SET(t.id,r.teams) )
OR(".$mid." = 0) ) 
AND u.id NOT IN($paidrows) 
AND u.id NOT IN ($rsrows) 
GROUP BY u.id";
```

Comment: *"this query is too long and will have unexpected results results"* - Based on what? This query isn't nearly pushing the limits in terms of 'longness'. Also your change turns the old style inner joins into left joins, while that part was supposed to work as it is.